# WatiN downloading files

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-11, watin

I am trying to use WatiN to do some screen scraping type of work. It runs on our site on a scheduler. I have no need to see the UI, I just need it to do the work. I can navigate the sites with no issue , but when trying to downlaod the files I have 2 problems.

1. Using IE 11 when it comes time to download , I get stuck on the open/save dialog that pops up. I have tried and tried and tried everything to have IE 11 auto download files, but to no avail. I edited the registry, and tried every option in the security tab, but no luck.  I tried using SendKey.Sendwait("{TAB}"), to mimic what would need to be pressed , but I get "access denied" I think the "ui" is locked.

so I tried Firefox,  firefox is easy to configure "automatic downlaods" .... but

2. FireFox wont even connect, I get:  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9997  I installed the appropriate jjsh addon and  install it globally for all users from the command line, but still no luck.

Any suggestions on how to disable that yellow bar that IE 11 puts at the bottom of the screen to annoy you , or what I might try with firefox? I believe configuring IE 8 to disable the yellow dialog bar is possible, but I am on a windows 8 machine , so I'm stuck with IE 11, or possibly 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep trying to find a solution but that solution will probably break in a next release of IE (based on previous experience) to be able to finally solve and be future proof (if there's such a thing in development....) I would suggest to navigate to the page that has the link and get the HREF portion of it and once you have that link just do the download using other ways, like the following:

(this is just pure C#, not watin)

```
string downloadURL = "http://example.com/retrievePDF.jsp?id=XXXXX";
client.DownloadFile(downloadURL, @"C:\temp\" + fName + ".pdf");
```

you should replace the downloadURL with the value on the HREF of your download link and you will be able to find the file where you specify it.